# Issues using a pipe to display the difference between two times given in miliseconds

Tags: rest, angular, typescript, momentjs

I am trying to display the difference between a purchase time which I receive from a REST API and the current time using a angular4 pipe.  When I use the pipe on the purchaseTime value for some reason it displays today's date/time instead of the difference between the two...  Any idea what i'm doing wrong here?

```
my code:

import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';
import * as moment from 'moment';

@Pipe({
  name: 'timeSpan'
})
export class TimeSpanPipe implements PipeTransform {

  transform(value: any, args?: any): any {
    let now = Date.now();
    let purchaseTime = +value;
    let span = moment.duration(now - purchaseTime);
    return moment(span.asMilliseconds()).format('MM:DD:hh:mm'); 
  }

}
```

Comment: what does `value` hold? A Date object? Or a date string? Or a timestamp?

Comment: @PierreDuc value holds a date in milliseconds